# Google keyboard on Ubuntu Linux to achieve voice typing

Tags: voice-recognition

Is it possible to install Google keyboard on Ubuntu Linux to achieve voice typing in any editor?

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution or alternative yet?

Answer (score -1):

There are many alternatives like [Dragonfly](https://github.com/dictation-toolbox/dragonfly).

Comment: with not the same quality